# PB 10 applications Windows 10 Compatible

Tags: windows, windows-10, powerbuilder

Does any one know if PB 10 compiled applications will be compatible to run on Windows 10?  Or any known issues migrating PB10 source to the newest version to run on Windows 10?

Comment: We haven't had problems running the applications on Windows 10. We have one development machine on Win 10 that has problems with TFS, specifically if you right click on the Workspace the IDE locks and must be killed.

Answer (score 0):

A [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172567/powerbuilder-10-windows-8-compatibility) was made some years ago regarding Windows 8 compatibility with PB10.

Bottom line is you need to test, test, and re-test your applications.  Migration from PB 10 to PB 12.6 shouldn't pose any major problems but again, it depends upon your applications.  If they use Windows API calls or external ActiveX type controls you may encounter issues.   SAP deprecated a few things in 12.6 but nothing major (unless you are using them of course).

Answer (score 0):

We have an ERP programmed in PB 12.5.2 Classic (started from 7 and been migrated all along) - and it works fine. We supplement the UI with custom built COM components (.NET 4.5) and everything works as expected in both Win 7 & Win 10 (notebooks, desktops & tablets).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no official support for windows 10. 
PB 12.5 supports Windows 7.
PB 12.6 supports Windows 8.
And Appeopn PB 2017 will support Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I also use powerbuilder on various machines and see no problem with Windows 10.  I even let the executable run on a linux ubuntu machines. No problem reported so far.